# File stores contents in one line but how to store it line by line.?

Tags: python, stdout

following code is to download
1)all links from http://www.adobe.com/support/security/  to 'urlfile'
2)Extract only "bulletins" links to 'urlsort'
3)Input 'urlsort' by reading line by line
4)Finally store all websource to 'content'

My problem is 'content' stores all websource in a single line but I want it to be stored line by line(as we see by pressing F12)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib,sys,re,os

'''f1=open('content1','r')
f=open('urlfile','w')'''
page = urllib.urlopen("http://www.adobe.com/support/security/")
page = page.read()

fileHandle = open('urlfile', 'w')


links = re.findall(r"<a.*?\s*href=\"(.*?)\".*?>(.*?)</a>", page)
for link in links:
    sys.stdout = fileHandle
    print ('%s' % (link[0]))
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
fileHandle.close()

 os.system("grep -i '\/support\/security\/bulletins\/apsb' urlfile |sort|uniq|sed -e    's/http:\/\/www.adobe.com//g' |sed -e 's/^/http:\/\/www.adobe.com/g' > urlsort") 

f = open('urlsort','r')
f1 = open('content','w')
for line in f.readlines():
    url=line.strip('\n')
    print url
    page1=urllib.urlopen(url)
    sys.stdout=f1
    print page1.readlines()
    sys.stdout=sys.__stdout__
    page1.close()
```

Comment: What troubles me is your print page1.readlines('\n'). Are you sure this is really the content of the page which is in your content file, or with some [] added, that is it is really the list that is printed ? In that case I think print '\n'.join(page1.readlines()) is what you really want. PS: as an added bonus, do you know that you can write print >>f1,'\n'.join(page1.readlines()) rather than doing your sys.stdout=f1 / sys.stdout=sys.__stdout__ gymnastic.

Comment: "Pressing F12" does not make sense without a context.  In your browser?  (Which browser?)

Comment: Google chrome,i said source of the web page(line by line).....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not taking into account the ludicrous reassigment of the standard output, what you are writing into `content` is a single array of all the lines per url from `urlsort`.

A simple addition to line 28: `print "".join(page1.readlines))` will do the trick.